# rails select field custom attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I currently have a scaffold with the default new, edit, create, etc. methods.

My new method looks like:

```
 def new
   @group = params[:id]
   @people = Person.all
```

Now i want to create a method "select" like

```
def select
    render action: 'select'
end
```

and the select.html.erb should only contain one select box to select the group, which I need as input for the new method.

How does a (form?) like this have to look like.

Answer (score 1):

First of all

```
def select
    render action: 'select'
end
```

For sure won't do anything and probably cause an infinite loop error, because `render :action=>your_action` renders action of controller, and here you render this action itself.

To interact with views, you need method

```
respont_to do |format|
format.html
end
```

As I understood, you need to use radio button. From API:

```
<%= radio_button_tag(:age, "child") %>
<%= label_tag(:age_child, "I am younger than 21") %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:age, "adult") %>
<%= label_tag(:age_adult, "I'm over 21") %>
```